# What is the t (threshold) parameter in scipy's fcluster / fclusterdata?

Tags: python, scipy, cluster-analysis

I am attempting some analysis using `scipy.cluster.hierarchy`. I get a nice dendrogram, but when I want to get actual cluster labels for my data, I have to set the `t` parameter for the function `fcluster` or `fclusterdata`. The docomentation only says it's a `float`, but what does the number actually mean? I would like to know to be able to set it properly. EDIT - for example, what `t` should I set, when I want *k* clusters and have *m* samples in my dataset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning of the threshold parameter depends on the `criterion` you set as documented in [scipy's api](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.fcluster.html#scipy.cluster.hierarchy.fcluster). As documented in the api there are the following 5 options:

1. `inconsistent`
2. `distance`
3. `maxclust`
4. `monocrit`
5. `maxclust_monocrit`

In both the `maxclust` and `maxclust_monocrit` criterion `t` is the maximum number of clusters to form. So concerning your edit you should set it to k.